# adding a property extension to lists, in F#

Tags: types, f#, extension-methods

as a followup to question: [type extension on a list in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703688/type-extension-on-a-list-in-f/62704145#62704145)

I am trying to figure out if I can extend lists with a property

Consider the code:

```
let a = []
if a.IsEmpty then ...
```

But I also have commonly:

```
if not a.IsEmpty then
```

which is not super readable, so I thought I'd do an extension (based on Tomas' answer in the question above):

```
[<Extension>]
type ListExtensions() =
    [<Extension>]
    static member IsNotEmpty(l: 'T list) = not l.IsEmpty
```

and it allows me to do:

```
if a.IsNotEmpty() then
```

but then I have:

```
if a.IsEmpty then // property
if a.IsNotEmpty() then // member
```

Is there a way to make a property extension so that IsNotEmpty is also a property?

Comment: I don't think there is!

Comment: I also don't think there is a way of doing this. But `not a.IsEmpty` is only one character longer than `a.IsNotEmpty` and the fact that it starts with `not` makes it very obvious that it's negated (which may be easy to miss when reading code that uses `a.IsNotEmpty`)

Comment: I thought it would help readability, but at the same time, it was mostly out of curiosity :)

Comment: I find it's less confusing to always name bools and bool returning things in the positive and then negate with `not` if needed.

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question but for this particular example it's idiomatic to do `match list with | [] -> ... | _ -> ...`

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't this be useful?:

```
type List<'T> with
    member this.IsNotEmpty with get() = not this.IsEmpty
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we should use type augmentation:

```
type List<'A> with
    member this.IsNotEmpty = this.IsEmpty |> not
let a = []
a.IsNotEmpty |> printfn "%b"
```

By this way, `IsNotEmpty` is a property.